# Correct Spring configuration for Liquibase's `preserveSchemaCase` parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I am not able to get  `preserveSchemaCase=true` ([ref](https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/home.html)) to apply using Spring's application.yaml. Any ideas?

The schema has a `spring.liquibase.parameters` field of type `Map<String,String>`, so I am not seeing what I am doing wrong - unless the Spring setting is called something else?

```yaml
spring:
  liquibase:
    parameters:
      preserveSchemaCase: true
      # these are all variations to try and hit the right one ...
      preserve-schema-case: true
      preserveSchemaCasing: true
      liquibase.preserveSchemaCase: true
      liquibase.preserve-schema-case: true
```

## Workarounds

### Env var

If I just do `LIQUIBASE_PRESERVE_SCHEMA_CASE=true mvn spring-boot:run` it works immediately

### System prop

I can also just add `System.setProperty("liquibase.preserveSchemaCase", "true")` to the `main` method.

Would prefer to use the Spring config, though!

The below is from a debugging session where I check what Liquibase is doing and it does not seem to use the `parameters` bag at all. It just looks up the value from the env vars.
[image]

Comment: I would try `spring.liquibase.preserve-schema-case=true` or equivalent in YML.

Comment: Based on https://contribute.liquibase.com/extensions-integrations/directory/integration-docs/springboot/springboot/

Comment: @Mar-Z That did not fly, unfortunately. It is not part of the schema (not a valid property), so Spring immediately exits with an error. The fact that the option is listed under parameters (linked above with ref) is why I was pretty sure it should be under the `parameters` property. I just can't get it recognized ...

Comment: If it is not in schema then you have no luck - this option is not available on Liquibase integration for Spring Boot. They are saying in the doc - only a subset of config is available.

Comment: The `parameters` map is for substitution of parameters in the change log itself. Like ${some.parameter}.

Comment: Ah, THANK YOU. That avoids moving further down that rabbit hole.