# Can I use liquibase.properties alongside a Spring config?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

[I tried for ages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77868364/correct-spring-configuration-for-liquibases-preserveschemacase-parameter?noredirect=1#comment137277591_77868364) to figure out a way to set `preserveSchemaCase` in Spring Boot's `application.yaml`, until someone pointed out that just a *subset* of the settings were available through Spring!

So, I tried moving some of the config out into `liquibase.properties`, but it does not do anything. Some searching [led me to believe that the liquibase config file is not actually picked up when using Spring Boot](https://forum.liquibase.org/t/liquibase-properties-file-not-being-picked-up-when-running-using-spring-bean-springliquibase/7675?u=fatso83). Is that so? Does that mean that setting these props not exposed by Spring is only achievable through code? As in `System.setProperty("liquibase.preserveSchemaCase", "true")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When relying on Spring Boot's auto-configuration to configure the Liquibase bean, you can only get the properties offered by Spring which are, as you've mentioned, a subset of Liquibase's set of properties.

Spring Boot's Liquibase bean configuration:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3d5cdb7715397db2b4b3260544624d0f919315b4/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java#L98

Spring Boot supported Liquibase properties (prefixed with `spring.liquibase`):
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseProperties.java

If you'd want to set additional properties, that are not offered by Spring, you could opt for creating a Liquibase bean manually: create a Configuration class and link `liquibase.properties` to this class via `@PropertySource` annotation and then declare a Liquibase bean in this class.

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:liquibase.properties")
public class LiquibaseConfig {

    @Value("${preserveSchemaCase}")
    private boolean preserveSchemaCase;

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml");
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource()); // Set your data source here

        // ... set other properties 
        
        liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(Collections.singletonMap("preserveSchemaCase", preserveSchemaCase));

        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

For the Spring offered Liquibase properties, you'd either want to move them all into `liquibase.properties` or you could get them from `application.yml` by providing Environment bean to this LiquibaseConfig configuration class. Either way, you need to call the appropriate setter on the liquibase bean manually for each property.